# Download image GDrive API from browser

Tags: javascript, download, google-drive-api

I try to retrieve all images within a google drive folder using their API. For now, I get all images as binary using this request:

```
const baseurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files"
const query = "'XXX'+in+parents"
const token = "YYY"

fetch(`${baseurl}?q=${query}&key=${token}&fields=files(id)`).then(...)
```

And I get sth like:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to turn this into a `<img ...>`. I tried with `btoa`, it throws an exeption (that the string contains errors). I tried to transform the string to [base64](https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841), but the final image is not valid. Any idea ?

Comment: the code you have pasted fetches a list of file IDs. Try pasting the code you have tried to fetch the image content and set in an img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the approach. Instead of downloading the file and trying to decode it, I just extract a downloadable link from the response (`webContentLink`) and fill the `src` attribute of my `<img ...>`:

```
const baseurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files"
const query = "'XXX'+in+parents"
const token = "YYY"

fetch(`${baseurl}?q=${q}&key=${key}&fields=files(webContentLink)`)
  .then((data: any) => data.json())
  .then((data: any) => data.files.map((f: any) => f.webContentLink))
  ...
```